# How to implement Google Custom vision .tflite model in flutter

Tags: image-processing, google-vision, tensorflow-lite

I was building image classifier app in flutter and the model was trained in Google autoML. When i copied downloaded .tflite and .txt file to flutter and run, it shows the following error

"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite tensor with type UINT8 and a Java object of type [[F (which is compatible with the TensorFlowLite type FLOAT32)"

Please help how can I implement it

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your model so I can't reproduce the issue. But from the error message, it seems that the model is expecting to have uint8 input, rather than the float32 input as you provided.

Could you try either feed the model with uint8 input or download a float32 model from AutoML (without quantization)?

Comment: I am not able to download unquatized AutoML model. Plus I don't know how to convert my image to uint8 format

Comment: Hi Fazil, You can find some information from this site: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization basically you'll need to calculate the quantized value using the quantization spec. Ideally you should be able to try the support lib https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/lite_support but unfortunately I don't think the metadata is added in the AutoML model.